# Data received on UDP socket with delay

Tags: sockets, udp

Randomly facing an issue where we see in wireshark,  RTP packet arrived much before but we receive the data on a socket with 20 or 30 seconds delay.
we do select on while loop every second and do receivefrom in application. application in c++
Its a random issue happens once in a 15-20 days. We use udp socket. Application restart fixing the issue.

Added many log statement to narrow down the issue to above problem stated. Any reason why this issue can happen?